# Changing background color input when contain word

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have code like below, when I put word "BH" or "bh" my background color will change on yellow. How change javascript code to detect contain word in long text? 
For example, when I put text like "Somethink text BH in input" background not change on yellow I would like to detect single letters like BH in long text

```js
function checkFilled() {
 var inputVal = document.getElementById("subEmail");
    if (inputVal.value == "BH" || inputVal.value == "bh") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else{
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}
 
checkFilled();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled();"/>
```

Comment: Check if the value `.includes` the substring you're looking for?

Comment: yes, how it will be in my code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `includes` is not supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Smollet777 Best not to cripple one's ability to write short, easy-to-understand code for the sake of obsolete browsers - that's what polyfills and Babel are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.match`:

```
function checkFilled() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("subEmail");
  if (inputVal.value.match("bh|BH")) {
    inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
  else{
    inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

checkFilled();
```

Comment: It's what I looking for! Thanks, Can I change this code and connect with CSS, change color by css code not directly in js like now)?

Comment: @Joe The only way to change the css dynamically is through javascript.